# NullPointerException when I have clearly referenced the file correctly

Tags: java

I'm writing a basic GUI for practice, and I want to include an image, and after double-checking *all* of my code, there remains a `NullPointerException` when I run it.

```
Image i;
ImageIcon ii;
```

...

```
public Pnl() {
    BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 5);
    setBackground(Color.GREEN); 

    x = 10;
    y = 10;

    ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("shrek.jpg"));
    i = ii.getImage();

    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    timer.start();
} // end of constructor
```

EDIT: The NPE occurs in the line where I initialize the `ImageIcon`

Comment: Try with `getResource("/shrek.jpg")`

Comment: we can't really help you if you don't tell us *where* the `NullPointerException` occurs...

Comment: And where did you put your `shrek.jpg` image?

Comment: As with all such situations, break the statement into two so you can check the value of `this.getClass().getResource("shrek.jpg")`, which clearly will be `null`.  Then figure out why it's not finding the file.

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for "getRecource(..)":

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

> A URL object for reading the resource, or **null** if the resource **could not be found** or the invoker doesn't have adequate privileges to get the resource.

Comment: He didn't provide infos. about location of his image. So your answer is a pure guess.

Comment: @brano He didn't, but this is the only possible explanation for an NPE on that line. We can't say exactly *why* it's not finding the resource, but it's clearly either not present or improperly named.

Comment: Ok ok..I withdrew my downvote. Although I voted to close question.